# Error calling a submit: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java

There is a Web Panel from where a Call is made to a Procedure as a Submit. The Submit is sent an empty String and a collection SDT as parameter. When it is called, it fails with this error: `java.io.NotSerializableException.`How can I solve this?

Comment: by posting more info and what you have tried I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thrown exception is telling you what is the problem. You need to make the required object to be serializable.
It can be done by implementing `java.io.Serializable` interface :

```
class MySerializableClass implements Serializable {}
```

Now MySerializableClass is serializable and can be used as bean etc.